# Getting firebase user detail when logged and ignoring when logged out

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a fragment that prints a message in textview depending on time of day and day of week. I want to print logged in first name but if user is logged out this first name should be ignored.
App works fine when logged in but i get Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference when I log out.

```
String userID;
String currentUserId;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
String mDayGreet;
String weekDay;
DatabaseReference dbReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
public static final String USER_ID_EXTRA_KEY = "EXTRA_KEY";

userID = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra(USER_ID_EXTRA_KEY);


    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (firebaseUser!= null) {
        currentUserId = firebaseUser.getUid();
    }


    dbReference.child("AllUsers").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("profile").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User userDetail = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

            Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat mFormatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
            String mDateString = mFormatDate.format(mCalendar.getTime());

            int time = Integer.parseInt(mDateString);
            TextView greeting = view.findViewById(R.id.greeting);
            int dayOfWeek = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            TextView dayInfo = view.findViewById(R.id.info);

            if (Calendar.MONDAY == dayOfWeek) {
                if (time >= 0 && time < 18) {
                    weekDay = getString(R.string.monday);
                }
            }

            dayInfo.setText(weekDay);

            if (time >= 0 && time < 12)
                if (currentUserId == null) {
                    mDayGreet = getString(R.string.morning);
                } else {
                    mDayGreet = getString(R.string.morning) + " " + userDetail.getFirstName();
                }

            greeting.setText(mDayGreet);
```

Comment: This exception means **FirebaseUser** or its session is null when user logged out. so just check null condition before calling `getUid()` method or every other methods called using Firebase Instance.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()` as the parameter of `child` method of database reference. But when the user is not logged in, the statement `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` returns null and eventually you will get the `NullPointerException` when you try to call a method on it.

One solution would be to save the user id in the shared preferences when the user is logged in, and if the user is not logged in next time, you can get the user id from shared preferences instead of `FirebaseAuth`.